# Saving the output of spider in a variable rather than in a file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am looking for a way to save the spider output in a python variable instead of saving it in a `json` file and reading it back in the program.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.wikipedia.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
                'text' : response.css(".jsl10n.localized-slogan::text").extract_first()
             }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.remove('result.json')
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'result.json'
    })

    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()
```

I want to avoid the below step and directly read the value instead of saving it on disk first

```
with io.open('result.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
        text = d[0]['text']
```

Comment: I think this is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993380/scrapy-store-returned-items-in-variables-to-use-in-main-script/48017202#48017202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `global` variable to store the output which solves my purpose.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

outputResponse = {}

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.wikipedia.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        global outputResponse
        outputResponse['text'] = response.css(".jsl10n.localized-slogan::text").extract_first()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.remove('result.json')
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    })

    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass an object into spider and change it, like this:

```py
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.wikipedia.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.outputResponse['text'] = response.css(".jsl10n.localized-slogan::text").extract_first()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.remove('result.json')

    outputResponse = {}

    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    })
    process.crawl(TestSpider, outputResponse=outputResponse)
    process.start()
```

This works, because every named argument passed to spider constructor is assigned to an instance as an attribute, that's why you can use `self.outputResponse` inside `parse` method and have access to an external object.

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you so much